# cocoa: drag files from my app (file paths contained in NSTableView) to other app (finder, mail, etc)

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview

My app has an array of file paths contained in a subclass of NSTableView, I would like to be able to drag those files (and folders) from my app to other applications.

I followed this article:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingDragAndDrop.html
but it didn't work.
This one: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001288-CEGJFDFG , using the 1st method (mouseDown and performDragOperation) kind of worked but something like mouseDragged would have been much better.

I have downloaded and looked at the DragNDropOutlineView example but I didn't find what I wanted (they are dragging file promises).

What am I missing?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I eventually managed to do that.  I followed the instruction on the 1st link (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingDragAndDrop.html) but I had to add the following lines in my awakeFromNib method to make it work:

```
[resultTable setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationNone forLocal:YES];  
[resultTable setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:NO];
```

resultTable being the instance of my subclass of NSTableView.